# what are the difference between blocks and functions in iphone

Tags: iphone

```
     double(^simpleBlock)(double,int, double ) = ^(double n3,int n1,double n2){
   NSLog(@"Block with Three parameter");
  return n1*n2*n3;
```

};

what are the difference between blocks and functions in iphone.Which one is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block is used for doing work on background thread.

Comment: Give Some more Differences also.

Comment: and also use as completation handler.